# How to create a textbox with Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

I want to create a textbox when I click with the mouse as I add a dot with a leaflet and write articles in it. How can I do this?

Example:
I want to add it to the map like this.

[image]

Comment: Just `map.on('click', function() { window.prompt() }`, perhaps? you might want to edit your question to add more detail.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I rearranged.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look in "Working with popups" example at https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/